# How to apply a style to a sibling element from another element

Tags: css, html-framework-7

I have the next HTML structure:

```
<div class="subnavbar">
  <div class="subnavbar-menu">
    <a href="#tab1" class="link1">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#tab2" class="link2">Link 2</a>
  </div>
  <div class="subnavbar-bar">
    <hr />
  </div>
</div>
```

I need to apply `margin-left: 50%` on `<hr>` element when **link2** is hover.

I've tried using:

```
.subnavbar .subnavbar-menu a.link2:hover > .subnavbar-bar hr { 
   margin-left: 50%; 
}
.subnavbar .subnavbar-menu a.link2:hover + .subnavbar-bar hr { 
   margin-left: 50%; 
}
.subnavbar .subnavbar-menu a.link2:hover ~ .subnavbar-bar hr { 
   margin-left: 50%; 
}
```

But nothing work, I have no idea ):

Comment: Not possible with just CSS and this markup.

Comment: I'm based on this demo [link]https://codepen.io/rm/pen/ldhon[/link] but on my example the hr element is on other div, I'm totally stuck

Comment: `>|+|~` is **not valid CSS**. Here's the reference for CSS selectors: https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/

Comment: **CSS cannot do this** , you can fake it average for the fun **only**  with `pointer-events`http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OpYaJo

Comment: SOLVED using jquery: $(document).on('mouseover', '.link2', function (){
$('hr').css('margin-left', '50%'); });

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What the heck is that selector `>|+|~` lol never have seen it in my life

Anyways if the `<hr>` had the same parent, you could do this with adjacent sibling selector:

**CSS**

```
.link2:hover + .subnavbar-menu hr {
  margin-left: 50%;
}
```

But since it has a different parent I don't believe this is possible with pure css.

**jQuery**

```
$('.link2').mouseover(function() {
    $('.subnavbar-bar hr').css('marginLeft', '50%');
}).mouseout(function() {
   $('.subnavbar-bar hr').css('marginLeft', 'auto');
});
```

Here is codepen example: http://codepen.io/StefanBobrowski/pen/qrGJga

Comment: lol >|+|~  = element > ... OR element + ... OR element ~ ... 
yeah, my bad

Answer (score 0):

you may use pseudo and float if [BFC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context) allows it :

```css
hr {
  overflow:hidden;
}

a.link2:hover:after {
  content:'';
  float:left;
  clear:left;
  height:1em;
  width:50%;
}

a:before {
  content:'';
  padding:0.5em 0;
  margin-bottom:0.3em;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="subnavbar">
  <div class="subnavbar-menu">
    <a href="#tab1" class="link1">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#tab2" class="link2">Link 2</a>
  </div>
  <div class="subnavbar-bar">
    <hr />
  </div>
</div>
```

or pointer-events

```css
hr {
  overflow:hidden;
}
.subnavbar-menu {
  pointer-events:none;
}
.subnavbar-menu:hover:after {
  content:'';
  float:left;
  clear:left;
  height:1em;
  width:50%;
}
.subnavbar-menu a {
  pointer-events:auto;
}
a:after {
  content:'';
  padding:0.5em 0;
  margin-bottom:0.3em;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="subnavbar">
  <div class="subnavbar-menu">
    <a href="#tab1" class="link1">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#tab2" class="link2">Link 2</a>
  </div>
  <div class="subnavbar-bar">
    <hr />
  </div>
</div>
```

**DISCLAIMER:** *(it just happens the selector and style you want can be faked)*

- `float` can break easily
- `pointer-events` is a bad idea