# Change the SVG label icon in a CSS dropdown menu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I found on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/erwincalvez/embed/NRjOKp) a CSS dropdown menu, a checkbox solution that I liked. I adapted it a little to my needs, excepting that I can't figure out **how to hide the close icon** when the menu is closed. I know about existing solutions, for example like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59572484/1354580), but I can't solve it in my case. Any suggestion?

**SOLVED** (see below code)

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

input#toggle-menu{
  display: none;
}

#search-toggle {
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 4px solid tomato;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.header-inner-wrapper{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 80px;

}
#searchform{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 84px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  transform: scaleY(0);
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transform-origin: 50% top;
}

#header-inner-wrapper label{
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  width: 60px;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 0;
  margin-top: -18px;
}

input#toggle-menu ~ #searchform {
  /* transform: scaleY(0); */
  animation: nav-out 1s ease-in-out normal forwards;
}

input#toggle-menu:checked ~ #searchform {
  /* transform: scaleY(1); */
  animation: nav-in 1s ease-in-out normal forwards;
}

@keyframes nav-in {
  0%{
    transform-origin: 50% top;
    transform: scaleY(0);
  }

  50%{
    transform: scaleY(1.3);
  }
  
  80%{
    transform: scaleY(0.9);
  }
  
  90%{
    transform: scaleY(1.05);
  }
  
  100%{
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
}

@keyframes nav-out {
  0%{
    transform-origin: left center;
    transform: scaleY(1);
   
  }
  
  50%, 60%{
    transform: translateX(-10%) rotateY(0);
    
  }
  
  
  80%{
    transform: translateX(100%);
   
  }
  
  99.9%{
     transform: translateX(100%) scaleX(1);
  }
  100%{
    transform: translateX(100%) scaleX(0);
     opacity: 1;
   
    /* transform: translateX(100%) rotateY(-90deg); */
   
   /* transform: translateX(0%) rotateY(60deg) scaleX(0.2) ;
    opacity: 0; */
    
    
  }
}

input#toggle-menu:checked ~ #header-inner-wrapper #iconsearch {
  display: none;
}

input#toggle-menu:not(:checked) ~ #header-inner-wrapper #iconclose {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="search-toggle" class="float-left">
  <input type="checkbox" id="toggle-menu">
  <div id="header-inner-wrapper" class="header-inner-wrapper">
    <label id="iconsearch" for="toggle-menu">
        <svg id="icon icon-search" viewBox="0 0 30 32">
            <path class="path1" d="M20.571 14.857q0-3.304-2.348-5.652t-5.652-2.348-5.652 2.348-2.348 5.652 2.348 5.652 5.652 2.348 5.652-2.348 2.348-5.652zM29.714 29.714q0 0.929-0.679 1.607t-1.607 0.679q-0.964 0-1.607-0.679l-6.125-6.107q-3.196 2.214-7.125 2.214-2.554 0-4.884-0.991t-4.018-2.679-2.679-4.018-0.991-4.884 0.991-4.884 2.679-4.018 4.018-2.679 4.884-0.991 4.884 0.991 4.018 2.679 2.679 4.018 0.991 4.884q0 3.929-2.214 7.125l6.125 6.125q0.661 0.661 0.661 1.607z"></path>
          </svg>
    </label>
    <label id="iconclose" for="toggle-menu">
      <svg id="icon icon-close" viewBox="0 0 25 32">
            <path class="path1" d="M23.179 23.607q0 0.714-0.5 1.214l-2.429 2.429q-0.5 0.5-1.214 0.5t-1.214-0.5l-5.25-5.25-5.25 5.25q-0.5 0.5-1.214 0.5t-1.214-0.5l-2.429-2.429q-0.5-0.5-0.5-1.214t0.5-1.214l5.25-5.25-5.25-5.25q-0.5-0.5-0.5-1.214t0.5-1.214l2.429-2.429q0.5-0.5 1.214-0.5t1.214 0.5l5.25 5.25 5.25-5.25q0.5-0.5 1.214-0.5t1.214 0.5l2.429 2.429q0.5 0.5 0.5 1.214t-0.5 1.214l-5.25 5.25 5.25 5.25q0.5 0.5 0.5 1.214z"></path>
</svg>
    </label>
  </div>

<div id="searchform">
    <form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="https://example.com">
        <textarea>Here will be a search form</textarea>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't see any checkboxes on the link?

Comment: this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43265849/how-to-apply-a-style-to-a-sibling-element-from-another-element#43265972](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43265849/how-to-apply-a-style-to-a-sibling-element-from-another-element#43265972) might help you

Comment: @IurieMalai "I found on CodePen a checkbox dropdown menu on click..." There is no checkbox dropdown menu in the CodePen link. That's what I meant...

Comment: @kunalpanchal Thank you, but the original code works without jQuery, I want the same.

Comment: @DeniJ. Check under the HTML button. Just copied from there: `<input type="checkbox" id="toggle-menu">` - https://codepen.io/erwincalvez/embed/NRjOKp